# React Hooks - console log doesn't show anything

Tags: reactjs

In the following code, I expect to see the image object in the console once I select a file. But it doesn't log anything. Also no errors.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ImageUpload = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0]);
      };
    };

  console.log(image);

  return (
    <>
      <input type='file' onChange={(e) => handleChange} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageUpload;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the `};` after `useState` a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Directly pass the function no need to create inline function

```
<input type='file' onChange={handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
(e) => handleChange
```

You are not calling the `handleChange` function.

Change to:

```
(e) => handleChange(e)
```